# Underscore template line break after each iteration

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to make line break after each iteration?

```
 <% _.each(depend, function(i) {%>  
   this.<%= i %> = <%= i %>; 
<%}); %>
```

Comment: I does not need use of html i am using this in node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use swing template for node he does this out of the box.

npm install swig --save

```
{% for dep in depend %}
  this.{{ dep }} = dep;
{%- endfor %}
```

And you can see the swig docs how to compile this, its like underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want a horizontal line after each iteration

```
 <% _.each(depend, function(i) {%>  
   this.<%= i %> = <%= i %>; 
   <hr/>
 <%}); %>
```